# how to use iphone ringtone in app

Tags: iphone

I want to use ringtones of iPhone in my app. Is this possible? Please help on iam stuck on this point,

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use or change the ringtones available programatically. Sorry to say that but Apple is damn conservative.

Comment: Or, opposes user-hostile behavior by applications. Call it "conservative" if you want, but I'm totally okay with this on a phone.

Comment: Or, tries to prevent misleading applications - "I'm pretending to ring the phone" sounds a bit fishy.

Comment: Well. From traditional computer OS design perspective, it's really advanced rather than conservative. Conservative design is permitting everything to user and just let them to be messed themselves until OS get crap. If you can't understand meaning of **user** has been changed from scientist/engineers to consumer, then you are in trouble in any of end-user UI app field.

Answer (score 0):

you can access ringtones in the following directory: /Library/Ringtones/