# Need to change ringtone settings of iPhone through my app

Tags: iphone, settings, ringtone

My requirement in the app is to set the ringtone of the iPhone through my app. Like I will choose the ringtone from my application and it has to be reflected in the iPhone ringtone setting..

can anybody help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this on with the current SDK

Comment: Are there any third party libraries which I could embed into my app to set the ringtone ?

Comment: As of now you cannot at all modify the ring tone functionality,it is a private API

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly from you app.Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593666/how-to-use-iphone-ringtone-in-app/4593859#4593859) for reference.

Cheers